# Testing .Net Library Options Don't Appear

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, xunit

I'm currently learning unit testing with C# in VS Code and I'm using the .Net framework, not .Net Core. When I try `Assert.Equal(exp, act)`, I have to force it in because it doesn't generate automatically and it thinks I want to type something else. How do I allow the Xunit testing library options to show up in VS Code?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I closed and reopened **VS Code** and that solved it. As I had only installed **Xunit**, it needed to be reopened to take effect.

[image]